# DateTime and TimeStamp Fields in Mysql are becoming null when saved from java code

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, gmail-api

I have a requirement to store the date as well as time into a field in mysql.

For that I tried using date time field in Mysql and from Entity class I am using below code to store the data

```
@Column(name = "SENTDATETIME")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
private java.sql.Date sentDateTime;
```

For the timestamp field in mysql using the below code from entity class

```
@Column(name = "SENTDATETIMESTAMP")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")
private java.sql.Timestamp sentDateTimeStamp;
```

Mails and faxes will be received by the application and date is retrieved from MimeMessage as below

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    MimeMessage message = null;
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");


    try {
        message = new MimeMessage(session, req.getInputStream());
        Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
        myobject.setSentDateTime(message.getSentDate());
        }
        catch(exception e)
        {
        }
```

After saving the object the date stored in the datetime is becoming null and there is no exception occuring.
I have tried to set the value into the timestamp and facing the same issue and the datetime and timestamp fields are null in database.